# Simple Makefile to do out of source build into a single build dir from multiple source trees

Tags: gnu-make

I have following simple Makefile that *almost* does what I want.

This compiles `.c` files from directories listed in `SRC_DIRS` into a single executable.

The source files are in `./src` and `../pmlin/master` and the intermediate files are supposed to be in directory `./build`

The problem is that this compiles files from `./src` to `./build` correctly,
but files from `./pmlin/master` end up in `./pmlin/master` and not `./build/pmlin/master`.

I've tried various things like removing the `../` from the paths in `OBJS` with `pathsubst` but at the end of the day after hours of googling and experimenting I've not been able to make this work.

```
TARGET_EXEC = aslac-calibrator

BUILD_DIR = ./build
SRC_DIRS = ./src ../pmlin/src/master
SRCS := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d) ../pmlin/src ../pmlin/src/devices
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

Comment: Does it matter where the intermediate files land, as long as the executable can be built, or is the problem more than cosmetic?

Comment: Cosmetic and matter of pride. Want all the immediate files to be in a single build directory and not litter my project root directory. I have several project like this and some have more 'out of the main' source tree references so I get more litter at root. Also, as it stands, that clean: target does not work now as it does not remove the litter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up with this solution where I turn the relative path to the other source trees into absolute paths with $(abspath). In this way
everything is compiled into the build directory and there no chance of a name conflict.

```
TARGET_EXEC = pmlin-demo

BUILD_DIR = ./build
PMLIN_DIR = $(abspath ../pmlin)
SRC_DIRS = ./src $(PMLIN_DIR)/src/master $(PMLIN_DIR)/src/slave
SRCS := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d) ../pmlin/src ../pmlin/src/devices
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CFLAGS += -target macos-x86_64
CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP 
LDFLAGS += -target macos-x86_64

$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p

all: pmlin-demo
```

Comment: I guess there is a theoretical chance of name conflict if the source directory has some/one special name but I can't be bothered to work that special case out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's take a look: first you have:

```
BUILD_DIR = ./build
SRC_DIRS = ./src ../pmlin/src/master
SRCS := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
```

(you could also write the `SRCS` as:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c,$(SRC_DIRS)))
```

but either way works).

Suppose you have the files `./src/foo.c` and `../pmlin/src/master/bar.c`.  After the wildcard, `SRCS` is:

```
SRCS := ./src/foo.c ../pmlin/src/master/bar.c
```

Then, `OBJS` will be:

```
OBJS := ./build/./src/foo.c.o ./build/../pmlin/src/master/bar.c.o
```

You can probably already see the problem.  When you build `bar.c.o`, the value of `$<` is `../pmlin/src/master/bar.c` and `$@` will be `./build/../pmlin/src/master/bar.c.o`, and the `..` in the source path means that the actual path of the target will be `./build/../`, which is just `./`.

One option is to have a makefile in each source directory and use recursive make to go build each directory.

A second option is to use VPATH; that would be something like:

```
BUILD_DIR = ./build
SRC_DIRS = ./src ../pmlin/src/master
SRCS := $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.c.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

VPATH := $(dir $(SRC_DIRS))
```

The downside with this is that all your object files from all your source directories will appear in a single output directory: if your different source directories may contain the same filename this won't work for you.

If none of those are what you want, then there's no possible way to address this other than writing multiple pattern rules.  A single pattern rule cannot  work because there's no way to write one pattern, with one `%` match, that does what you want for the different directories, because they don't have the same root.  You can see this if you convert the filenames to a fully-qualified path; let's say your current working directory is `/code`, then the files you want are:

```
/code/src/foo.c              -> /code/src/build/foo.c.o
/code/pmlin/src/master/bar.c -> /code/src/build/pmlin/src/master/bar.c.o
```

If you look at these, there is no one single path you can replace with `%` that will work in ALL these different paths.

If you were willing to put the `build` directory in the common parent, instead of under the `src` directory, then you could do it by using `abspath` on all your paths; in that case you'd have:

```
/code/src/foo.c              -> /code/build/src/foo.c.o
/code/pmlin/src/master/bar.c -> /code/build/pmlin/src/master/bar.c.o
```

Now you can see that there's a common path `/code` that can be used for `%` that works with all the paths.

Comment: The first solution, even with possibility of name conflict, seems to be preferable for my current case.

I will try it and come back and accept this if I make it work. Thank you for your answer.